# How to create an index over an property which is a list of objects in OrientDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb, oriento

I'd like a class that stores a structure such as this:

```
{
  name: "blabla",
  metaData: [ {a: "mya"}, { a:"mya2"} ]  
}
```

`

Now, I would like to have an **index** over the metaData[?].**a** fields.

1. What is the best way to represent this metaData in a schema? As an embeddedList?
2. Is it possible to have that index i want?
3. If so, who should the query for retrieving an entity by it's "a" value should look like?
4. Alternatively, if we have, instead of that metaData, a field called "myAs" that is a 
   simple array of string - would it be easier?

Note that i'm using the [Node.JS oriento](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the index you want is possible, but if you do what you say in point 4, it's possible to define an index (I defined it as **unique**, but others will work).

You could:

```
create class Test
create property Test.name string
create property Test.metaData embeddedlist string

insert into Test set name = 'blabla', metaData = ['mya', 'mya2']

CREATE INDEX Test.metaData UNIQUE

insert into Test set metaData = ['mya', 'mya2'] # this will throw an exception
```

The query you asked in point 3 might be something like:

```
select from Test where 'mya' in metaData
```

**UPDATE**

You can also index an embeddedmap. (See [here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Create-Index.html#examples-of-index-for-thumbs-property-of-class-movie))

```
create property Test.metaDataTwo embeddedmap string
create index myIndex on Test (metaDataTwo by value) unique

insert into Test set name = 'blabla', metaDataTwo = {'prop1':'value1', 'prop2':'value2'}
insert into Test set metaDataTwo = {'prop3':'value1'}  # this will throw an exception
```

The query to use such index should be:

```
select from Test where ( metaDataTwo containskey 'prop1' ) and (  metaDataTwo['prop1'] = 'value1' )
```

Comment: Assuming an array will be used, yes, that would be the query. A question that is still open: will it be indexed, which means one index entry per array item (mongodb does that).

Comment: I think it indexes the whole list.

Comment: See that OrientDB does not support indexing in complex data structures. See [this issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3101)